# Is it perceived to be rude if you don't see "please" when you asked to change your question, answer?

Tags: discussion

#### Examples

In a comment to a question:

> Don't put the relevant to your question info in the comments. Update your question instead.

In response to comments from OP that change how the question can be answered.

In a comment to an answer:

> Use X instead of Y because Z.

Here it is implied that the answer could be improved by replacing `Y` with `X`.

The context is programming questions/answers.

I'm asking about personal feelings in such cases. How do you reword the examples so that they would be perceived as being nice?

Does it depend on the country and its culture?

Comment: It also depends on how you spell it. For example, apparently saying "plz" in India is fine because people there seem to have no problem using chatspeak in professional contexts, whereas everyone else considers that unprofessional, lazy, rude, insincere, etc.

Comment: @BoltClock: is that from personal experience or what?

Comment: I'd write something like "Instead of adding [xxx] in a comment, you can simply edit your question to add more information.", though I personally wouldn't find such a comment to be particularly rude.

Comment: @OneKitten: I've never been there physically, but assuming 90% of the demographic here that publicizes who they are and where they come from isn't outright lying about themselves, it seems to be ingrained into their online culture, because it's strangely nearly absent from other cultures.

Comment: VTC as opinion based. `I'm asking about personal feelings in such cases.` - don't. Personal feelings are irrelevant on a Q/A site, we care about facts, not about someones personal perception of niceness. This site is not about personal interactions, please don't try to make it that way. Said differently, we don't care about OP or a single person being offended - a comment would have to be rude/offensive in general to be inappropriate for the site. E.g. I'm extremely offended by people calling me "sir" in a comment, but I'm aware this is a personal thing and don't make a fuss about it.

Comment: @l4mpi: there is no such thing as being *rude/offensive in general*. Each person has his own views about what is *rude/offensive in general* (I know it might be hard to explain to a fish that it is in a water). "personal feelings" are facts, not opinions: "what do you feel?" and "what is your opinion about what you should feel?" are different questions.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You want to know the specific personal feelings of all SO users? I don't think so. Also, I wasn't attempting to discuss psychology or philosophy with you; maybe I should have worded my point differently: There is an (admittedly fuzzy) agreed-upon consent of things not to do in a professional environment like SO, e.g. excessive use of swear words or personal attacks (I doubt you will find any sane, serious person disagreeing here). These kinds of comments should go. Anything else should stay, as personal feelings of a comment being rude or nice are way too arbitrary to be useful.

Answer (score 6):

If you do say "please," and "thank you," the place to say that is in comments.  But, in general, we value brevity, clarity and helpfulness over social trivialities here.  Get to the point, upvote posts you find helpful, use proper English and occasionally contribute to keeping the site clean, and your efforts will be widely appreciated whether you say "please" or not.

To be specific about comment etiquette, it's more important to state specifically and clearly what sort of clarification you need in your comment, than it is to be concerned about social lubricant.  If everyone simply refrained from using words like RTFM and stayed professional, I'd gladly dispense with "please."

Worth noting: you can say "please" and still be rude.

Comment: "If you do say 'please,' and 'thank you,' the place to say that is in comments." But don't tell anyone that we'll remove them after the fact.

Comment: Is it a No i.e., you don't find the requests rude even if they have no "please" inside?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'll leave that for you as an exercise.

Comment: Is it a humor or you are just rude?